# Is there a way to catch/disable the "Edit text, input mode" message

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I've got an edittext control on my screen. 
When I tap into it I have two problems.
1.) the cursor doesn't show up where I tap. 

2.) if I keep my finger on the screen I get prompted with "Edit text --- Input method"

This question is about the second problem. 
I don't want to present the user with this question... Is there a way to not present the user with this? I think, if a user wants to change their input method, they should go to the settings.

---

Adjunct... Is there perhaps another text editing control?